# Annotating data in Doccano

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-annotations, doccano

Does anyone know why I do not get the tags in my dataset as shown on the tutorials/examples? I've highlighted a Dutch word with the tag 'direct medical relevance' but it doesn't appear as tagged when I press the label shortcut.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
[image: Transcription data with one 'annotated' word]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about support for a third-party application

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug to me, the project repo was updated a few days ago.

The demo has the same problem for me as the one you describe, meaning that nothing happens on mouse button release and I can't set any labels: https://doccano.herokuapp.com/demo/sentiment-analysis

The NER demo which uses a slightly different script still works for me: https://doccano.herokuapp.com/demo/named-entity-recognition

So you could see if you find an [issue](https://github.com/doccano/doccano/issues) for this problem (or write one yourself) or you can try to clone and go to an older commit before this problem.

From my personal experience while I found Doccano alright to work with for a while I found there to generally be a lot of bugs and quirks around the frontend interface which can give you a hard time if you try to annotate a large corpus. Also I dislike the fact that you can annotate string spans which are not following the token spans, since that caused me to misclick and having to correct it a lot, but that might be a personal issue. I switched to [Universal Data Tool](https://udt.dev/)s Named Entity Recognition Tool which worked better for me since it does the mentioned things differently and can be run entirely in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I see what you mean with the bugs. the first few i ran into i just overlooked because they didn't hinder my ability to work but this is quite a significant one as I can't even use the same tag multiple times in a single transcription. I've got quite a large corpus, 100+ transcriptions of 20-30 minute conversations. I'll check out UDT!